# regex to match text between two closest words

Tags: java, regex

could you help me with regex to match text between two closest words, please?

For example:

```
text KEYWORD1 text KEYWORD1 text KEYWORD2 text KEYWORD2
```

The result must be:

```
KEYWORD1 text KEYWORD2
```

This doesn't work, which is predictable:

```
(KEYWORD1).*(KEYWORD2)
```

Is it even possible to accomplish this with regexp? If so, how it will work with finite state machine?
Java regexp syntax would be the best. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look at greedy vs non-greedy regex.

Comment: [The correct answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27939123/3832970). Below answers feature a corrupt tempered greedy token. Please ignore those regexps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:

```
String val="text KEYWORD1 text KEYWORD1 text KEYWORD2 text KEYWORD2";
String REGEX="KEYWORD1((.(?!KEYWORD1))+?)KEYWORD2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(val);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Check this figure to see , how this is working :

[image]

[**Explanation :**](http://regex101.com/r/vY5cA0)

1st Capturing group `((.(?!KEYWORD1))+?)`

2nd Capturing group `(.(?!KEYWORD1))+?`

Quantifier ( `+?` ): Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

> Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.
>   Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all
>   iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not
>   interested in the data

`.` matches any character (except newline)
`(?!KEYWORD1)` Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
`KEYWORD1` matches the characters `KEYWORD1` literally (case sensitive)
`KEYWORD2` matches the characters `KEYWORD2` literally (case sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookahead assertion:

```
String myString =
    "text KEYWORD1 text KEYWORD1 text KEYWORD2 text KEYWORD2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("KEYWORD1((.(?!KEYWORD1))+?)KEYWORD2");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
String word = "";
if (matcher.find())
    word = matcher.group(1);

// word => " text "
```

See [Demo](http://ideone.com/4YinFR)

Answer (score -1):

why not use LevenshteinDistance in apache commons? it does just what you need. take a look at the javadoc http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. Honestly I don't want additional dependency for a such simple task.