# Regex, select closest match

Tags: python, regex

Assume the following word sequence

```
BLA text text text  text text text BLA text text text text LOOK text text text BLA text text BLA
```

What I would like to do is to extract the text from BLA to LOOK, but the BLA which is the closest to look. I.e. I would like to get

```
BLA text text text text LOOK
```

How should I do that using regular expressions? I got one solution which works, but which is exteremely inefficient.

```
BLA(?!.*?BLA.*?LOOK).*?LOOK
```

Is there a better and more performant way to achieve matching this pattern?

What I would like to do is: I would like to match BLA, then forward lookahead until either positive fordward lookahead with LOOK or negative lookahead with BLA. But I don't know a way to put this into a regular expression.

As a engine I use re in python.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
(?s)BLA(?:(?!BLA).)*?LOOK
```

Try this. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/12).

Alternatively, use

```
BLA(?:(?!BLA|LOOK)[\s\S])*LOOK
```

To be safer.

Comment: OK, so in short to find the first occurence in Regex, we need to have: `sometext.*?LOOK` which will match sometext and any number characters up until the **first** occurence of **LOOK**

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki yes....you can use the 2nd regex is you want closest `somtext` and `look`

Comment: Omg, finally I found the correct one. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to extract the desired text is to use the [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) technique, which matches a series of individual characters that do not begin an unwanted string.

```
r'\bBLA\b(?:(?!\bBLA\b).)*\bLOOK\b'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/N1NjEM/1/) | [Python code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php)

```
\bBLA\b        : match 'BLA' with word boundaries
(?:            : begin non-capture group
  (?!\bBLA\b)  : negative lookahead asserts following characters are not
                 'BLA' with word boundaries
  .            : match any character
)              : end non-capture group
*              : execute non-capture group 0+ times
\bLOOK\b       : match 'LOOK' with word boundaries
```

Word boundaries are included to avoid matching words such as `BLACK` and  `TRAILBLAZER`.

Answer (score -2):

simply find text between LOOK and BLA without BLA

```
In : re.search(r'BLA [^(BLA)]+ LOOK', 'BLA text text text  text text text BLA text text text text LOOK text text text BLA text text BLA').group()
Out: 'BLA text text text text LOOK'
```

:-)

Comment: Oh... it would be that easy :-) Thanks!

Comment: the problem is: It does not work if I use the expression e.g. on

    BLA text text text  text text text BLA text teLxt text text LOOK text text text bla text text BLA

so if there is a L between BLA and LOOK

Comment: I looks as if you need to revise you regular expression knowledge. Becuase `[^(BLA)]+` does mean that it would not match `BLA` rather it wouldnt match `B` or `(` or `L` etc