# Find the closest text with optional string

Tags: python, regex

I have [similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938851/regex-select-closest-match) except there is some optional digits (Fax number) in the pattern.

```
content = """Generator London ABC / FI9
Phone +758 00 000000000
E-Mail london.abcd@gen.in
Fax
Generate order no 546465438
Generate order date 29.04.2018
Country of Use
Page 1/ 3
Generator London ABC  / FI9
Phone +758 91 702 122222
E-Mail london.abcd@gen.in
Fax
Generate order no 4504967662
Generate order date 29.01.2018
Country of Use
Page 2/ 3
Payment terms:
30 days - 2 %, 45 days net
Supplier
Generator London ABC  / 3I9
Phone +758 91 702 122222
E-Mail london.abcd@gen.in
Fax +07023400800 1234 
XI54545454 ZI41 8263 8815 1100
+2939 218932 000
Total Profit Total Budget
...
"""
```

Observe the last occurrence of Fax, Fax number is not consistent but the `Fax` string always stays.

I have hundreds of files with this format and have to extract the exact text in between the Fax (except Fax no) and Total Profit.

```
$re.findall(r'Fax\s((?:(?!Fax).)*?)Total', content , re.DOTALL|re.M)
['+07023400800 1234\nXI54545454 ZI41 8263 8815 1100\n+2939 218932 000\n']
```

How can I get rid of Fax number using by improving regular expression pattern.

Expected result:

```
['XI54545454 ZI41 8263 8815 1100\n+2939 218932 000\n']
```

I don't want to go with manual text processing such as [result[0].split('\n')[1:]], as this is my generic method.

I tried some patterns at my own but no luck.

Comment: Try [`^Fax[^\n\r]*[\r\n]+((?:(?!Fax).)*?)[\r\n]Total`](https://regex101.com/r/myfpMs/1). Probably, a better one will be [`^Fax\b.*((?:[\r\n](?!Total|Fax).*)+)[\r\n]Total`](https://regex101.com/r/myfpMs/2) with no `re.DOTALL` modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - This is crazy, how can you do that within 2 mins...! I have been trying to fix it since last couple of hours. You are genius. Please answer I will accept. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest matching the text after `Fax` that is the first word on a line, then match the whole line after it without capturing, then capture any line that does not start with `Fax` or `Total` and up to the line that starts with `Total`:

```
re.findall(r'(?m)^Fax\b.*((?:[\r\n](?!Total|Fax).*)+)[\r\n]Total', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/myfpMs/2). You will probably have to strip the whitespace from it, but it is more efficient and precise than `^Fax[^\n\r]*[\r\n]+((?:(?!Fax).)*?)[\r\n]Total` because this one will prevent matches with `Fax` *anywhere* between lines starting with `Fax` and `Total`.

**Details**

- `(?m)` - the `re.MULTILINE` inline modifier
- `^` - start of the line
- `Fax\b` - a whole word `Fax`
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `((?:[\r\n](?!Total|Fax).*)+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more repetitions of

  - `[\r\n]` -  a CR or LF symbol
  - `(?!Total|Fax)` - not followed with `Total` or `Fax` (replace with `(?!(?:Total|Fax)\b)` to only match them as whole words)
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
- `[\r\n]` - a CR or LF
- `Total` - the word `Total` (add `\b` to require a whole word, `Total\b`)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

```
import re

content = """Generator London ABC / FI9
Phone +758 00 000000000
E-Mail london.abcd@gen.in
Fax
Generate order no 546465438
Generate order date 29.04.2018
Country of Use
Page 1/ 3
Generator London ABC  / FI9
Phone +758 91 702 122222
E-Mail london.abcd@gen.in
Fax
Generate order no 4504967662
Generate order date 29.01.2018
Country of Use
Page 2/ 3
Payment terms:
30 days - 2 %, 45 days net
Supplier
Generator London ABC  / 3I9
Phone +758 91 702 122222
E-Mail london.abcd@gen.in
Fax +07023400800 1234 
XI54545454 ZI41 8263 8815 1100
+2939 218932 000
Total Profit Total Budget
...
"""

print re.findall(r'Fax\s[\+0-9\s]+((?:(?!Fax).)*?)Total', content , re.DOTALL|re.M)
```

Here we have updated regex for Fax with [+0-9\s], so that it will consider '+', '0-9' digits and \s for any space in the number. Hope this will help.